# How to add cells based off of a specific integer?

Tags: r, vector, sapply

I want to add values from a column. They go in sequence:

```
0,225,2352,34234,23442,23456,0,123,...
```

I want to add the values from 0 until the following 0 but not including the second.
For example, i want an output of
`(0+225+2352+34234+23442+23456),(0+123+,...,),...`

I want to store them as a new column of totals

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution in base R is

```
sapply(split(x, cumsum(x == 0)), sum)
```

With `split` you basically create groups of elements that you want to `sum` together using `sapply`. The final result will be a named numeric vector.

---

Sample data

```
x <- c(0,225,2352,34234,23442,23456,0,123,2,0,1,42)
sapply(split(x, cumsum(x == 0)), sum)
#     1     2     3  
# 83709   125    43
```

Comment: or simply `aggregate(x ~ cumsum(x == 0), FUN = sum)`

Comment: It's a valid alternative, of course. On such small sample data, my solution is much faster according to `microbenchmark`